# Buttons inside a datatable

Tags: javascript, html, button, datatable

I am new to JS, and I'm trying to do something easy but I can't.

I create a datatable, last column has buttons, but when I click on them, nothing happens.

My Datatable charges after click on a button. (btn-search)

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#btn-search').on('click', function() {

        $.ajax({
                type:        "GET",
                url:"{{myurlapi }}",
                }).done(function (result) {
                    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "data":result.data,
                    "columns": [
                            { "data": "id"  },
                            { "data": "name" },
                            { "data": null }
                        ],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        { "searchable": false,
                          "orderable": false,
                          "targets": 0
                        },
                        { width: '3%',
                          targets: 0
                        },
                        { targets: -1,
                          data: null,
                          defaultContent: '<div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" class=" btn btn-view"><span> <i class="icon-plus"></i></span> </button></div>'
                        },
                                   ],
                    "processing": true,
                    "retrieve": true,
                    "searching": false
            } );
              table.clear().draw();
              table.rows.add(result).draw();
            });
    });

             $('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-view', function (e) {
                   alert('something')
     } );


});
```

```html
<div class="col-6">
            <button id='btn-search' class="btn btn-primary px-4">Search</button>
          </div>

<div class='card-body'>
                <table id="example"
                        class="table text-right table-bordered table-striped nowrap"
                        width="100%">
                 <thea

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Are you properly binding click event to `.btn-view`?

Comment: Did you try re-adding the "on.click" event in the console AFTER loading the table? Does the table load for a while (I.E. big table)?

Comment: i put it after btn-search function but it does not work

Comment: I can see that you put it after btn-search but based on your code it looks to me like its firing on dom load which will not add the click event to anything added later on. Copy paste your code in the console AFTER loading the table (manually) and see if anything happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the on.click event way too soon. If you fire it on dom load it will ONLY work for buttons that are already in the DOM. Anything that you add later on (append, replace whatever) will not fire the on.click event.

Try this ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-search').on('click', function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{myurlapi }}",
        }).done(function(result) {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                "data": result.data,
                "columns": [{
                        "data": "id"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": null
                    }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [{
                        "searchable": false,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "targets": 0
                    },
                    {
                        width: '3%',
                        targets: 0
                    },
                    {
                        targets: -1,
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: '<div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" class=" btn btn-view"><span> <i class="icon-plus"></i></span> </button></div>'
                    },
                ],
                "processing": true,
                "retrieve": true,
                "searching": false
            });
            table.clear().draw();
            table.rows.add(result).draw();
        });
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-view', function(e) {
            alert('something')
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: AjaxComplete would run on completion of ANY ajax request on page. Unless you have only 1 request to get that table data this may not be ideal as on completion of ANY ajax request you will have event bind on buttons which may already have another event bind to them.

Comment: ^ Good point. I assumed he only has 1 ajax call on the page (the most common scenario when using datatables). If thats not the case, promises might help (never used them yet since i'm trying to work around things like the above) -> https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: i only have one ajax call, each time i click on my search button.  Each time i click on inline buttons i will open a new page with id information, I try: var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(), but it's not working. how i can pass table to here? sorry as i said i am new on this

Comment: When you make a call to external page to open you need to pass on variables like data via post or get method. For example the url to open in new window for row id 17 can be //whatever.com/id/ or //whatever.com/?objectid=id.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is that your click events is bind to elements which are not on the table when page loads. When you load the data the column that contains button get loaded but you are still missing the click events on them.

Please [read this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) that tells how to add events on Complete load of table.

In javascript when you place a selector it only can be applied to loaded elements unless you place it in a "code that watches the dom". In your case you dont need to watch DOM all the time as it is in your control to run code once your buttons are loaded in DOM.

If you use the above technique mentioned in initComplete function you will be able to debug it. I have not copied examples here as they are already mentioned on that link however there are many ways to check for data loaded in table and I recommend using the one that library provides so in future you can update datatables and other libraries without any issues.